# How can I be signed in on meta, when main doesn't know who I am?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

Once again I appear to be *persona non notata* in `main`, since the login tells me there's nobody with my email address, but here I am on `meta`, complaining about it, with my name at the top of the page.

Will miracles never cease?

**Late-breaking Edit:** [The same thing happened to me on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319/how-come-im-logged-in-on-meta-but-main-doesnt-know-me-on-this-se-and-on).

Comment: Well, I managed to log in as myself, but now there are two John Lawlers here, both of them me. And none on Linguistics SE, because I still can't log in there; so I've apparently achieved Quantum Ego Teleportation. I may wait before Accepting any Answers here; I've been asked to on Ling SE Meta, but since I can't log in there all I can do is check the feedback box.

Comment: Your personal login issue (not the meta/main one, which I can't touch, but the one you mention in the comment above) should be fixed now, and you should be able to login to Linguistics.

Comment: I was logged in when I arrived. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, we piggy-back on the main site's authentication cookie to initially create your meta cookie.  This is why clicking "log in" on a meta site will redirect you to the main site's Log In page.

However, if the main site's cookie is somehow removed, you can still be logged into the meta.

If this happens, just log in again on the main site.

We're going to change how this works to help avoid this duality: **if you're logged out of the main site, you'll also be logged out of the meta**.  This change will go in next week.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened before, to myself. Namely, I log off the main, but I'm still logged into meta. Can be quite worrying.

Fortunately, people don't usually go to meta, so they can't usurp my identity here.

Comment: Except I didn't log off. It logged me off. Both SEs. But only main. Not meta. Bug or feature?